# crop ratio getting changed when expanding crop area in image_cropper flutter

Tags: android, flutter, image-cropper

How to lock aspect ratio when **1:1,4:3 or 16:9** crop aspect ratio select. When original ratio selected make aspect ratio unlock.

> It is working proper in iOS, But getting issue in android platform.

Here is code I have used.

```
  val = (await ImageCropper.cropImage(
  sourcePath: pickedFile!.path,
  compressQuality: 100,
  maxHeight: 700,
  maxWidth: 700,
  compressFormat: ImageCompressFormat.jpg,
  androidUiSettings: AndroidUiSettings(
      toolbarColor: ColorConstants.primaryColor,
      toolbarWidgetColor: ColorConstants.customBlackColor,
      lockAspectRatio: false,
      toolbarTitle: "Wood",
      activeControlsWidgetColor: ColorConstants.primaryColor),

  iosUiSettings: IOSUiSettings(
      resetButtonHidden: false,
      aspectRatioLockEnabled: false,
      rotateButtonsHidden: false,
      rotateClockwiseButtonHidden: false)))!;
```

Answer (score 0):

For android you need to set the `lockAspectRatio` to `true`. This is the default value. You set it to `false`.